# Error debugging in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Can somebody please tell what might be the cause of the following error?

> Error in meta-data for
>   com.admin.AdminLogin.empId:
>   Unsupported primary key type: int

Comment: Can you show us some of your code so that we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

int is unsupported type for AppEngine keys, use Long instead.

See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Keys

Hope this help